# basic authentication not working javascript

Tags: javascript, api

I am having some trouble getting a few things working. I am trying to connect through basic authentication. I am using javascript in my HTML code. I get the following error message: " Failed to load http://**********/connections?*********  : Response for preflight is invalid (redirect)" where I have redacted the API endpoint.  The code I wrote is the following.

```js
 
 
  var Key = "something";
  var Secret = "something else";
  var url = 'http://**********';
 
     $.ajax({
      
      headers: {
         'X-******-Key':Key,
         'X-**********Secret':Secret,
         'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
         },

      
      type: "GET",
      url: url,
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(json) {
        alert("Success", json);
      },
       
      error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
         alert(textStatus, errorThrown);
      },
      
      beforeSend: function (xhr) {
       
      
       
        xhr.setRequestHeader ("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa(Key + ":" + Secret));
      },
      type: 'GET',
      contentType: 'json',
     });
```

```html
 <html>
<head>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>

hi
</html>
```

You can substitute the API end points and secret and Key to try the code for a common  basic authentication API to try the code. I don't have access to the Server. I know it is still possible to make this work because someone else said they have this working. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: When an api has a secret key they don't want you to expose it in browser. Use a proxy on your server to talk to the api

Comment: @charlietfl so I can perhaps connect using Nodejs instead and it should work right?

Comment: Although you hide your key in this question, it is going to be visible to all who visit your website. (via console)

You should create a node microservice which has this key and let it talk to the real server. Your front end should talk to your node microservice.

Comment: @CharlieH  hey I tried doing this in  node, but got this error :  at errnoException (dns.js:28:10)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:76:26)
  code: 'ENOTFOUND',
  errno: 'ENOTFOUND',
  syscall: 'getaddrinfo',

Comment: @charlietfl hey I tried doing this in node, but got this error : at errnoException (dns.js:28:10) at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:76:26) code: 'ENOTFOUND', errno: 'ENOTFOUND', syscall: 'getaddrinfo',

Comment: I think you should post another question about your error in node - that it is going to be a completely different approach than this.

Comment: @CharlieH The new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47827757/errors-trying-to-access-an-api-endpoint-via-basic-auth

Comment: @charlietfl The new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47827757/errors-trying-to-access-an-api-endpoint-via-basic-auth

Answer (score 1):

> Response for preflight is invalid (redirect)

Your server doesn't handle CORS properly.

Browsers won't let fetch data via ajax if the request is made to an external domain unless the server handles CORS properly and CORS headers are available in the responses.

Please read the article:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS